# API/Framework design: setting modes/environments (such as dev mode, etc)

Tags: asp.net, api, frameworks, dependency-injection

I was wondering what the best way of setting modes for a reusable web framework written for asp.net, suitable for manual configuration or with a dependency injection framework.

---

A bit of background and explanation: We have a framework designed in house that has a couple of modes:

- application mode: dev, test, prod. Set in config file.
- a "kiosk" mode: on, off. Application specific, overridden in code.
- a runtime debug mode: if dev application mode, and a certain URL parameter is set.
- specific debug flags: display borders, show performance info, etc, set by application.
- future modes...

So we have a few different modes that can be set in a config file, or during runtime or by the application at startup depending on its primary usage.

The problem is that these modes have been controlled via a single 'god' class in the framework that reads the config file, the url parameters, as well as having virtual properties that can be overridden to specify the 'kiosk' mode.

So this god class has a lot of references to services which I can pull out and define in the constructor for dependency injection. However checks for the different modes are spread throughout the codebase (if dev mode... or if kiosk mode). Much like how it makes sense to access a logging library via static methods, I wonder if it would make more sense to just have a few static methods that the application would set in asp.net's ApplicationStart event.

One of the aims of this code reshuffle is to help with unit testing. In regards to modes, only the kiosk and non-kiosk modes need to be tested as the debug modes are only for developers.

Options:

1. Singleton class/static method for setting modes, called at start of application
2. Have dev/kiosk specific objects and pass them in as dependencies, configured at startup. For example instead of just MailService, there would be DevMailService and KioskMailService as well. This would mean a lot of extra work to begin with.
3. Classes that require knowledge about dev/kiosk mode or debug options have properties to enable/disable. It is up to the user to check that he/she is setting them all correctly. (sensible defaults for debug mode)
4. Or modes are set in constructor of classes as boolean parameters. (probably more useful for kiosk mode which must be set correctly)
5. A special "mode service class" that is passed in through the constructor for all classes that require knowledge about the mode.
6. A special debug mode service class that can be set via properties if necessary, by default set to null object.
7. A combination of choices.

I was leaning towards properties for debug settings and flags (3), constructor parameters for setting kiosk mode (4) but have newer code written with specific Kiosk and non-Kiosk classes (2).  Not quite sure how to deal with handling debug mode set via url parameters though, possibly using a debug service set via a property with a null object default. (6)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing to keep in mind is being pragmatic. Does the extra work of the code reshuffle outweigh the benefits? To me it sounds like a significant architectural change, and the current model seems to be pretty okay already.

For one of my own projects I've also decided not to go for the architectural change, just because it we would lose trust in the system. Sometimes it's better to *know* what does not work well, instead of having a lot of confusion by *guessing* how to do it right.